# How to fix this regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to process some string date which print out like this

```
'node0, node1 0.04, node8 11.11, node14 72.21\n'
'node1, node46 1247.25, node6 20.59, node13 64.94\n'
```

I want to find all the floating points here , this is the code I use

```
for node in nodes
    pattern= re.compile('(?<!node)\d+.\d+')
    distance = pattern.findall(node)
```

however the result is like this

```
['0.04', '11.11', '4 72']
```

while what i want is this

```
['0.04', '11.11', '72.21']
```

Any suggestion on fixing this regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions, a `.` character is interpreted as a wildcard character and can match (almost) any character.  Thus your search pattern actually allows a digit or set of digits, followed by any character, followed by another digit or set of digits.  To stop this interpretation of the dot character, escape it with a backslash `\`.

(An aside: You don't need to compile your regex pattern inside your loop. In fact, that will slow your code down.)

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<!node)\d+\.\d+')
for node in nodes:
    distance = pattern.findall(node)
    print distance
```

output:

> ['0.04', '11.11', '72.21']
>   ['1247.25', '20.59', '64.94']

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought move the pattern out

Answer (score 4):

The `.` in your expression is unescaped.

```
for node in nodes:
    pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!node)\d+\.\d+")
    distance = pattern.findall(node)
```

Comment: So what doest the r do here?

Comment: The `r"..."` means that any ``\`` in the string is automatically escaped (which wasn't a problem here but would have been if you had something like `\n` in there for whatever reason`).